# Android GridView has black background on API8 (at least)

Tags: android, gridview

Works fine on Kitkat, but has issues in API 8 (real device) and emulator.

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY33Y.png

Code:

-- main layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/inner_background" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <GridView
         android:id="@+id/busListGrid"       
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
         android:divider="@null"
         android:dividerHeight="0px"
         android:background="#00000000"
         android:listSelector="@drawable/bus_grid_selector"
         android:numColumns="3"
         android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
         android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
         android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style_busgrid" >

        </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

--single item xml for custom adapter:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lv.sezy.satiksme.rezekne.layouts.SquareView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bus_grid_selector" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/busGridSingleHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/empty"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bus_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:text="@string/tester"
            android:textColor="@color/busGridTextColor"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</lv.sezy.satiksme.rezekne.layouts.SquareView>
```

-- bus_grid_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bus_grid_regular" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bus_grid_focus" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bus_grid_focus" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

--bus_grid_regular:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#90FFFFFF" />

            <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I was able to fix similar issue with ListView by adding

android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

bus it does not help with GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with LinearLayout background @drawable/empty, which was just and empty shape.
Appears that API8 interprets empty shape as black shape.